# Redirect with custom headers in WebAPI

Tags: .net-core

Basically I have a web API  written .NET Core. Having a GET API exposed, from that API I need to redirect to another URL with a custom header. I have tried  the redirect method, however it is not forwarding the custom headers.

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974289/mvc-4-redirecttoaction-does-not-see-custom-header) may helpful.

Comment: Thanks , but no luck still